# Find the equation of an ellipse by given point and foci

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Find the equation of the ellipse:

[image]

The equation of a standard ellipse centered at the origin is $$\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$ From the diagram we can infer that $c=20$, which is $c^2=400=a^2-b^2$. The coordinates of $A$ should satisfy the equation of the ellipse, so $$\dfrac{169}{a^2}+\dfrac{432}{b^2}=1\iff169b^2+432a^2=a^2b^2.$$ Now we are left with finding $a^2$ and $b^2$ from $$\begin{cases}a^2-b^2=400\Rightarrow a^2=400+b^2\\169b^2+432a^2=a^2b^2\end{cases}$$ We get $169b^2+432(400+b^2)=b^2(400+b^2)$ which is biquadratic for $b$. Is there a way to find $a^2$ and $b^2$ without such gross calculations?

Answer (score 1):

The ellipse is the locus of constant foci distance sum.

As you further already said: $c^2=a^2-b^2$, thus by symmetry it becomes clear that this sum $s$ is related by $(s/2)^2 = c^2+b^2=a^2$, i.e. $s=2a$.

Thus
$$a=\frac{dist(F_1,A)+dist(A,F_2)}2$$

--- rk

Comment: Thanks! I really didn't get how you found that relation between the sum $AF_1+AF_2$, where $F_2$ is the other focus, and $a,b$ and $c$. How did you use symmetry?

Comment: simply Pythagoras applied for each of the upper quadrants.

Comment: So we have $|AF_1|=\sqrt{33^2+432}=\sqrt{1089+432}=\sqrt{1521}=39$ and $|AF_2|=\sqrt{49+432}=\sqrt{481}$. The given answer is $\dfrac{x^2}{676}+\dfrac{y^2}{576}=1$, and I have checked it with GeoGebra. With this radical for $|AF_2|$ that answer cannot be reached.

Comment: you wrote above (in the question): $c^2=400=a^2-b^2$, whereas your proposed solution in the comment above provide $a^2-b^2=676-576=100$ only.